# replace multiple values of a list with one call python

Tags: python, list

Given an initial list, I want to change the list using one function call :
This:

```
A=[cat,dog,ostritch]
```

To This:

```
  A=[sal,fred,martin]
```

I understand we can do

```
A.replace('cat', 'sal')
A.replace('dog', 'fred')
```

I would like to make some sort of mapping ie so I can just call the replace function only once. ie:

```
replace mapping=[cat:sal,dog:fred, ostritch:martin]
A.replace(A,replace_mapping)
```

Comment: Just use the mapping to create a new list with the values instead

Comment: Do you know about dictionaries ?

Comment: Does it need to be a function call? If you made a proper dictionary `{'cat':'sal', ...}` then `A[:] = [replace_mapping[old] for old in A]`. And BTW, please make this a working example. Like `"sal"` instead of `sal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the mapping with a dictionary.

```
mapping = {cat:sal,dog:fred, ostritch:martin}
A = [mapping.get(i, i) for i in A]
```

`mapping.get(i, i)` will get the corresponding value from `mapping`, and default to the original value if there's no such entry.

Answer (score 1):

The most pythonic way is to use a list comprehension:

```
a = ['cat', 'dog', 'ostritch']
replace_mapping = {'cat': 'sal',
                   'dog': 'fred',
                   'ostritch': 'martin'}
a = [replace_mapping.get(word, word) for word in a]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['sal', 'fred', 'martin']
```